# Nativescript real device date and time

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, nativescript

Is there a way I can get the date and time of device ? The auto one. If the user disables the auto in date and time and chooses his own date and time, it would crash my app. I am also using firebase with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to detect that info on iOS, but on Android you could do this.

```
if (application.android) {
        if (android.provider.Settings.Global.getInt(application.android.context.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME, 0) !== 1) {
            console.log("Date / Time preference is not set to auto!!!");
        }
    }
```

On iOS the only option may be comparing the local date time with the server's date time with a simple api, make sure you include the timezone info.